# How can on emulate a keyboard or mouse click?

Tags: c++, wpf, visual-studio-2010, keyboard, mouse

I'm currently using a Windows 8 Laptop and I have no way to use middle mouse clicks other than my mouse (which just happened to get break). So I thought that there must be a way to make a program running in the background that whenever i press a key of my choosing I can make it work like any other key (in this case a middle click).

Though I have no idea how could someone accomplish this and I ended asking you guys.
If it's important I'll make the program in c++, so if you know how to do it there it'll be better, but I'm sure it wouldn't be that hard to change from another language.

Thank You for your time!!

Comment: It's one line in AHK.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write your own tool.

E.g. AutoHotkey allows you to use the remap functionality for such a situation.

If you prefer, you can write yourself a simple AutoIt script which has the hotkey hardcoded. Use the [HotKeySet](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm) function to register a hotkey and the [MouseClick](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) function to emulate a mouseclick at the current position of the cursor.

Corresponding methods in the Win32 API would be `RegisterHotKey` and `SendInput`.

There is no driver-independent default hotkey for this task in Windows, although Synaptic touchpads may allow emulation of the middle mouse-button when you press left and right button simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes AHK would work. Just a few more details on an answer.

1) Download AHK at  http://www.autohotkey.com
2) To create an AHK script, simply create a new text file with the file extension ".ahk" when you save it.
3) Right click your new AHK file and choose "edit script" option.
4) Type the following:

```
z:: ;when you press 'z' the middle mouse button is pressed down
MouseClick, m,,,,, D 
KeyWait, z 
MouseClick, m,,,,, U 
return
```

5) Save the file again.
6) To launch the script, simply double click it.
7) Whenever you press "z" on keyboard, a middle mouse click will be simulated.

you can change z to other letters

good luck.